# Не получается получить текст из элемента selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Вот HTML страница:

```
<p class="error">overflow of memory!!!!</p>
```

Вот код, с помощью которого пытаюсь заполучить текст ошибки:

```
err = driver.find_element_by_class_name("error")
err.text
```

В итоге ничего не выводится, причем сам элемент обнаружается.
Как данный текст получить-то?)

Comment: Дайте ссылку на страницу

Comment: driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p.error") Указывайте более точные идентификатор. Думаю вы просто нашли другой блок с таким классом

Comment: да, вы правы, находился другой элемент

Comment: используйте ```bs4```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте найти все элементы, добавив `s` в слово `elements` и переберите по очереди все найденные элементы:

```
err = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("error")
for e in err:
    print(e.text)
```